# Angular Material - embed date picker on page load / html tag

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I've a requirement in which the material datepicker (the actual datepicker itself not the icon) has to be displayed in the page.

*The page should always displays the datepicker rather than clicking on the icon.*

Could someone help / guide me on this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the same problem but unfortunately
`<mat-datepicker opened="true" #picker></mat-datepicker>` doesn't work.

I have analyzed the source code as well, seems they don't handle this scenario or not working.

What I have done to make this work is to give focus to the element and go ahead and open from that.

```
 <input matInput id="matInputEle" [matDatepicker]="picker" (focus)="picker.open()" >
```

add a function inside your .ts

```
ngOnInit() { 
   setTimeout(()=>{
        document.getElementById("matInputEle").focus();
   },1);
}
```

Hope this helps.

We need to wait for this issue got fixed in Angular material until I will go with this.

Comment: Give visibility Hidden ( visibility:hidden ) css property to the input box

Comment: Do we need to add toggle button also?   <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" (focus)="picker.open()">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>

Answer (score 3):

You can use `MatCalendar` component when you import `MatDatepickerModule`

```html
<mat-calendar (selectedChange)="onDateChange($event)"></mat-calendar>
```

inputs and outputs are not documented yet, but you can checkout the sources for what the API is [/material/datepicker/calendar.ts#L157](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/datepicker/calendar.ts#L157)

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

`<mat-datepicker opened="true" #picker></mat-datepicker>`

Comment: could you please provide any working plunker link. It doesn't seem to be working for me.